# Trouble with require in my env.rb file

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to learn rspec/cucumber for the the RSpec book from the pragmatic programmers site. Up until now all of the examples have worked and I think I'm doing everything correctly. However I keep getting the following error.

`cucumber features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature

~                                                                  │no such file to load -- codebreaker (LoadError)`

I know the codebreaker.rb file is there and it has the right content. Am I missing something? I'm using the same version of ruby and related gems as the book suggest.

[image]

`$LOAD_PATH  << File.expand_path('../../../lib', __FILE__)
require 'codebreaker'`

Comment: is your `codebreaker.rb` present inside the `lib` directory? Please specify the heirarchy of the folder/files in your app.

Comment: Yes it is in lib. lib/codebreaker.rb/features/support is the structure.

Comment: `features` folder should be in same level as `lib` not inside the `lib`. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Its looking for the `codebreaker.rb` inside the  `codebreaker/lib/codebreaker.rb` but your heirarchy is wrong. There are not in the same level. so is the problem. Try to create a folder by name `lib` and place your `codebreaker.rb` inside it and i think it would do. See my image for hierarchy.

& the lines in env.rb should be:

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path('../../../lib', __FILE__) 
require 'codebreaker'
```

Notice:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually the book is totally correct with the directory structure. I was reading it wrong.